# remove jsessionid in url rewrite in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, jsessionid

I am using spring MVC and having a problem in jsessionid, what I found is that jsessionid is injected in the url if cookies isn't enabled in the browser producing a url like that:

http://localhost/categories;jsessionid=Bsls4aQFXA5RUDcmZKV5iw?cid=13001

Actually there is no problem with browsers but when Google crawl my site, and seems Google crawlers don't have cookies :), they store urls of my site in that form and my site appears in search results  having URLs like that ones containing jsessionid.

Actually it's running without any problems, but I prefer to have URLs appear in Google search results clear without jsessionid.

Any help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To the point: simply don't let your app create sessions as long as users do not login or perform POST actions. Do not call `request.getSession()` or `request.getSession(true)`. Do not create nor manage session scoped beans for non-logged-in users. Ensure that the frameworks which you're using do not unnecessarily create sessions without that you say it to do so.

If this is *really* impossible due to the way your application is designed or due to the limitations/bugs of the (MVC) frameworks used, then your best bet is to redirect Googlebot requests to URLs without JSESSIONID identifier. You can use [Tuckey's URL rewrite filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) for this (which is, say, the Java variant of Apache HTTPD's well-known [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)). Here's an extract of relevance from its [configuration examples page](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/guide.html).

> #### Hide jsessionid for requests from googlebot.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> <outbound-rule>
>      <name>Strip URL Session ID's</name>
>      <note>
>          Strip ;jsession=XXX from urls passed through response.encodeURL().
>          The characters ? and # are the only things we can use to find out where the jsessionid ends.
>          The expression in 'from' below contains three capture groups, the last two being optional.
>              1, everything before ;jesessionid
>              2, everything after ;jesessionid=XXX starting with a ? (to get the query string) up to #
>              3, everything ;jesessionid=XXX and optionally ?XXX starting with a # (to get the target)
>          eg,
>          from index.jsp;jsessionid=sss?qqq to index.jsp?qqq
>          from index.jsp;jsessionid=sss?qqq#ttt to index.jsp?qqq#ttt
>          from index.jsp;jsessionid=asdasdasdsadsadasd#dfds - index.jsp#dfds
>          from u.jsp;jsessionid=wert.hg - u.jsp
>          from /;jsessionid=tyu - /
>      </note>
>      <condition name="user-agent">googlebot</condition>
>      <from>^(.*?)(?:\;jsessionid=[^\?#]*)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$</from>
>      <to>$1$2$3</to>
>  </outbound-rule>
> ```

Comment: I am always impressed with your answers.

Comment: BalusC ought to write books. I am first in line to buy it:)

Answer (score 11):

Spring can be configured to not do that:
[Why jsessionid is appended to each url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795036/why-jsessionid-is-appended-to-each-url)

Web applications can be configured to block it:
http://randomcoder.org/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use Spring http tag.
Go to your applicationFilterChain bean that defines your Spring filter chains.
Normally you will have a filter called httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter or something very close, that is based of the class org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter or inherits from it.
Add the property:

```
<property name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepositoryNoJSession"/>
```

And add the bean:

```
<bean id="securityContextRepositoryNoJSession" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository">
    <property name="disableUrlRewriting" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

This should be equivalent to setting disable-url-rewriting to true

Answer (score 0):

I would insert a filter that if it detects a bot (like googlebot) uses a custom HttpServletResponse which overrides the encodeUrl methods to simply return the raw URL. If the filter does not detect a bot it would simply let the chain continue which should let url encoding etc continue as per the default.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get rid off jsessionid in your url is to change to  tag on login page where is calling j_spring_security_check to

```
<c:url var="authUrl" value="/static/j_spring_security_check" />
    <form action="${authUrl}" method="post">
```